# How to use the lifetime on AsRef

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm having a hard time understanding how to use lifetimes with the code below. I understand that explicit lifetimes are necessary to aid the compiler in understanding when it can hold/release data but in this particular case, `url.serialize()` generates an anonymous string and I'm not really sure how to resolve this issue.

```
impl AsRef<str> for RequestUri {
    #[inline]
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &str {
        match self {        
           &RequestUri::AbsoluteUri(ref url) => url.serialize().as_ref() 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The docs for [`AsRef`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) state:

> A cheap, reference-to-reference conversion.

However, your code is not a reference-to-reference conversion, and it's not "cheap" (for certain interpretations of "cheap").

You don't tell us what library `RequestUri::AbsoluteUri` or `url.serialize` come from, so I can only guess that it returns a `String`. Whoever calls `serialize` can take ownership of the string, or can let it be dropped.

In your example, you take the `String` and call `as_ref` on that, which returns an `&str`. However, *nothing owns the `String`*. As soon as the block ends, that `String` will be dropped and any references will be invalid.

There is no solution to the problem you have presented us using the information you've given.

Comment: Thank you for the information. The url is from rust-url. I'll continue to see if there's an alternative solution to this issue.