# How do I specify the lifetime of an AsRef?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to write a function that joins two iterables whose items can be converted into `OsStr` references and have had a tremendous amount of difficulty trying to specify the reference's lifetime.

```rust
use std::convert::AsRef;
use std::ffi::OsStr;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
#[must_use = "join_args is lazy and does nothing unless consumed"]
pub struct JoinArgs<'a, A: 'a, B: 'a> {
    a: A,
    b: B,
    state: JoinState,

    phantomA: PhantomData<&'a A>,
    phantomB: PhantomData<&'a B>,
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
enum JoinState {
    Both,
    Front,
    Back,
}

/// Chains two iterable argument lists.
pub fn join_args<'a, I1, S1, I2, S2>(iter1: I1, iter2: I2) -> JoinArgs<'a, I1::IntoIter, I2::IntoIter>
where
    I1: IntoIterator<Item = S1>,
    S1: AsRef<OsStr> + 'a,
    I2: IntoIterator<Item = S2>,
    S2: AsRef<OsStr> + 'a
{
    let a = iter1.into_iter();
    let b = iter2.into_iter();
    JoinArgs{a, b, state: JoinState::Both, phantomA: PhantomData, phantomB: PhantomData}
}

impl<'a, A, SA, B, SB> Iterator for JoinArgs<'a, A, B>
where
    A: Iterator<Item = SA>,
    SA: AsRef<OsStr> + 'a,
    B: Iterator<Item = SB>,
    SB: AsRef<OsStr> + 'a
{
    type Item = &'a OsStr;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        // All throughout here, I'm getting E0597 errors.
        match self.state {
            JoinState::Both => match self.a.next() {
                Some(x) => Some(x.as_ref()),
                None => {
                    self.state = JoinState::Back;
                    self.b.next().map(|x| x.as_ref())
                }
            },
            JoinState::Front => self.a.next().map(|x| x.as_ref()),
            JoinState::Back => self.b.next().map(|x| x.as_ref()),
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to clean up a bunch of code I have where I'm using `map` and `chain` to coerce the types myself (like in the test below).  If there's a better way to do this, I'm all ears. :)

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    use std::ffi::OsString;

    #[test]
    fn test_join_args() {
        let a = &[OsStr::new("abc"), OsStr::new("def")];
        let b = vec![OsString::from("ghi")];
        let result: Vec<&OsStr> = join_args(a, &b).collect();
        assert_eq!(result, [
                   OsStr::new("abc"),
                   OsStr::new("def"),
                   OsStr::new("ghi"),
        ]);
    }
}
```

(This is on Rust stable, version 1.23.0)

Comment: While complete, your example isn't really *minimal*. It appears you just copy-pasted your entire file in. What does the `DoubleEndedIterator` have to do with the problem? Or the implementation of `size_hint`? Please review how to create a [MCVE].

Comment: Really, this is a duplicate of [How to use the lifetime on AsRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32062866/how-to-use-the-lifetime-on-asref) — you are trying to take a reference to an owned value that will go out of scope (`Some(x) => Some(x.as_ref())`)

Comment: Thanks, removed the suggested superfluous parts.  I wanted to keep in the test to show usage, since as you can see, a and b would stay alive for the length of the test, so it seems like there ought to be a way to describe this in Rust.  I'm still learning the language, so it's difficult for me to know whether my approach is wrong or something specific that I'm doing is wrong.

Comment: Also, FYI, you don't need `S1`/`S2`; you can just say `I1::Item: AsRef<OsStr> + 'a`.

Comment: No, I don't think this is a duplicate of that question.  I'm specifically using types that contain references to OsStr.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You don't**.

`AsRef` is a trait and its definition is fixed:

```
pub trait AsRef<T>
where
    T: ?Sized, 
{
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &T;
}
```

It can *only* be used to take a reference to one thing and get another reference with the same lifetime.

Your code would allow an `Iterator<Item = OsString>`:

```
use std::ffi::{OsStr, OsString};

fn proof<'a, I>(_: I)
where
    I: Iterator,
    I::Item: AsRef<OsStr> + 'a,
{}

fn main() {
    proof(vec![OsString::new()].into_iter());
}
```

If you then called `AsRef` on the item, you'd have a reference to something that doesn't live beyond the function. However, you are attempting to return that reference, which would be invalid. Thus, Rust has prevented you from introducing memory unsafety; hooray!

This is the exact same problem as [How to use the lifetime on AsRef](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32062866/155423)

---

The good news is that you can express what you want, you just need to state that your iterator *returns references*:

```
impl<'a, A, B, S1, S2> Iterator for JoinArgs<'a, A, B>
where
    A: Iterator<Item = &'a S1>,
    S1: AsRef<OsStr> + 'a,
    B: Iterator<Item = &'a S2>,
    S2: AsRef<OsStr> + 'a,
{
    // ...
}
```

---

As an aside, you don't need to have the `PhantomData` or the lifetime on your struct:

```
use std::convert::AsRef;
use std::ffi::OsStr;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
#[must_use = "join_args is lazy and does nothing unless consumed"]
pub struct JoinArgs<A, B> {
    a: A,
    b: B,
    state: JoinState,
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
enum JoinState {
    Both,
    Front,
    Back,
}

/// Chains two iterable argument lists.
pub fn join_args<I1, I2>(iter1: I1, iter2: I2) -> JoinArgs<I1::IntoIter, I2::IntoIter>
where
    I1: IntoIterator,
    I2: IntoIterator,
{
    JoinArgs {
        a: iter1.into_iter(),
        b: iter2.into_iter(),
        state: JoinState::Both,
    }
}

impl<'a, A, B, S1, S2> Iterator for JoinArgs<A, B>
where
    A: Iterator<Item = &'a S1>,
    S1: AsRef<OsStr> + 'a,
    B: Iterator<Item = &'a S2>,
    S2: AsRef<OsStr> + 'a,
{
    type Item = &'a OsStr;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        match self.state {
            JoinState::Both => match self.a.next() {
                Some(x) => Some(x.as_ref()),
                None => {
                    self.state = JoinState::Back;
                    self.b.next().map(AsRef::as_ref)
                }
            },
            JoinState::Front => self.a.next().map(AsRef::as_ref),
            JoinState::Back => self.b.next().map(AsRef::as_ref),
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    use std::ffi::OsString;

    #[test]
    fn test_join_args() {
        let a = &[OsStr::new("abc"), OsStr::new("def")];
        let b = vec![OsString::from("ghi")];
        let result: Vec<&OsStr> = join_args(a, &b).collect();
        assert_eq!(
            result,
            [OsStr::new("abc"), OsStr::new("def"), OsStr::new("ghi"),]
        );
    }
}
```

---

See also:

- [How to use the lifetime on AsRef](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32062866/155423)

Comment: Adding `&'a` into the Iterator type bounds did the trick, thanks!

Comment: One last tweak that I found in making this work well in my program: separating the lifetime parameters and declaring that the iterator returns the shorter of the two.

Comment: @RossLight that seems very unlikely to have a useful effect. The lifetimes need to be unified to produce the end iterator, so there's no reason to have multiple distinct input lifetimes. What sample of code didn't work before you made this change? Is this with my last edit which no longer has the lifetime on the struct?

Comment: I want to produce an iterator over two sources that have distinct lifetimes (imagine a and b in my test are in different scopes), and have it return references that are valid for the shorter of the two lifetimes: https://gist.github.com/zombiezen/802979e9d64bd82ad76760ad9675a3de

Comment: @RossLight my point is that having two input lifetimes makes no sense if you only have one output lifetime. The code presented here [already works if `a` and `b` are in different scopes](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3fb0334ae920825de6a52ccdb8f46ad1&version=stable).

Comment: The code I was trying to use looked like [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5d49508554ab9ffc3d97fdd3f8edeb69&version=stable).  I realize that the way I tried to bound the output lifetime doesn't work if I flip argument order, so now I'm thoroughly confused.